# How to remove autofill emails on Chrome

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome

I have a **15" MacBook Pro 2016** and I can't figure out how can I remove the saved auto-fill emails like I can on Windows/Linux using the keyboard:

1. Select one of the suggested emails from the drop down via arrows
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>
3. And viola the email is removed/forgotten

I've found this [link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142893?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) on Google Support which suggests that I use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> on my Mac and it should do the same, but for one laptops keyboard **does not** have the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, and even though I have the *delete_forward* key remapped over <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>it does nothing.

Is there any other way I can do this, I'm only interested in solutions via the keyboard, not the other solutions using Chrome's settings etc...

#### Pick of the auto fill drop down:

[image: autofill example]

Comment: Two things....1) It's *delete backward* or *Backspace*.  2) Are you expecting a "hidden, undocumented" keystroke to do what you want in lieu of a broken keyboard and a resistance to using the settings in Chrome?

Comment: 1) I've remapped the **Capslock** to `delete_or_backspace` and still it does not remove them from the list...
2) I'm not sure what you've said

Comment: You have a broken delete key and remapping doesn't work and you're unwilling to use settings...the only thing I can suggest is to fix the keyboard or use an external one.

Comment: The keyboard is not broke, it is just designed without that button. Yeah remapping doesnt seem to work... I know how to do it via settings, but itsa chore, so I wanted to learn to do it the faster way. Ty for responding.

Comment: The Delete key mentioned by Google is the “backspace” key ... which on my Mac keyboard is very clearly labeled Delete. Fn+Delete (backwards) is the equivalent of the (forward) Delete key on a full sized Windows keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

You have the correct answer. Here is a question on Superuser.SE that lists the keyboard shortcuts for multiple keyboards, include Mac laptops.

https://superuser.com/questions/175250/how-to-remove-one-or-all-auto-complete-text-entries-in-chrome

Comment: Thank you for showing this question to me, but non of the suggested methods worked, and the comments themselves state that it does not work on new MacBook Pros... I guess I'll have to go the settings way

Comment: I use the fn+shift+delete on my MacBook Pro and it works just fine. Not sure why yours wouldn't be functioning the same.

Comment: Which MacBookPro do you have? The one I have (**2016 15''**) has the keyboard layout without the `delete` key.

Comment: MacBook Pro 2017 with touch bar. The key in the top right corner says `Delete` even though it acts as the backspace.

Comment: Yeah I've tried doing `fn+shift+backspace(delete)` but to no avail... :[

Answer (score 1):

**If you are loging in with your google account in Chrome browser:**
It can be done by **signed out your google account** after clear all the autofill setting in Chrome setting and un-sync auto-fill setting. Then you will not get any auto fill drop down even though you sign in with your google account again.

Comment: This won't help enable me to use the `Shift + Delete` shortcut

Answer (score 1):

1. Focus the relevant input.
2. Use the arrow keys to highlight the item you would like to remove.
3. <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>